# Lightning Component Custom Link

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

Anyone already created a Lightning Component similar to custom links in classic? Ideally it will do a google search based on the Account Name?

Any tutorials or guide is much appreciated.

[http://www.google.com/search?q={!Account.Name}](http://www.google.com/search?q=%7B!Account.Name%7D)

Thank you,

Comment: you can create Formula Field which will generate this URL, will it work for you?

Comment: We need this added to a separate tab in lightning page layou

Comment: and how do you plan to pass Account information?

Comment: to be honest I don't have any ideas on how to do it. That's why I'm looking for some guidance or tutorials. I already tried to search but I haven't found any relevant info about my problem

Comment: can you add then some additional details on context of the problem. Where you want to display information (Account page context, some other page, Community, etc.), what are your requirements for Customization, etc.

Comment: I'm planning to add a new tab in the Lightning page layout that only shows the custom links. It says here that I need to write a Lightning component to achieve my requirement. https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dz41AAC

Comment: I think you can do this now with Formula field + Dynamic forms which will show your link fields